# Having trouble associating two users when adding a friend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Thanks for visiting

Whenever I click on Add a friend I get "friend added" but upon checking my console it says Friendship id: 10, user_id: 2, friend_id: 0, created_at: "2015-09-11 05:05:27", updated_at: "2015-09-11 05:05:27"> meaning it's adding but not associating with a friend_id. Can someone help me figure out why it's not saving friend_id whenever I click add a friend. Thank you for all your help.

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "friendships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
root "users#index"

  resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users
```

**Users/show**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <% if user.user_name != current_user.user_name %>
  <% if @friendshiplink.nil? %>
   <%= user.user_name %>
   <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(friend_id: user), method: :post %>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to(
       ("Unfollow"),
      "/friendships/#{ @friendshiplink.id }",
      method: :delete) %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key:  "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user
```

**Friendship Model**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

**User Controller**

```
def show
 @users = User.all
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 current_user
 if @current_user
    @followerlink = Follower.where(leader_id: @user.id,
                             follower_id: @current_user.id).first
    @friendshiplink = Friendship.where(user_id: @user.id,
                                friend_id: @current_user.id).first
 end
end
```

**Friendship Controller**

```
def create
 @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id])
 if @friendship.save
  flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
  redirect_to root_url
 else
  flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
  redirect_to root_url
 end
end

def destroy
 @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
 @friendship.destroy
 flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
 redirect_to current_user
end

def friendship_params
 params.require(:friendship).permit(:friend_id, :user_id)
end
```

Thanks again for all the help. If there are any question or I'm missing a part of my code which may be needed, Please ask.

Comment: Please post your params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the issue but give it a try:

```
<%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(friend_id: user.id), method: :post %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to "Add Friend", { action: :create, controller: 'friendship',:friend_id => user.id }, method:"post" %>
```

Also to make sure of error please add your `params` from your `console`

**UPDATE: do it in simplest way**

```
def create
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.build
  @friendship.friend_id = params[:friend_id]
  @friendship.user_id = current_user.id
  if @friendship.save
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the first part and there were no changes. Second part created an error of No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"friendship", :friend_id=>1}. Sorry to ask but how do I find my params in console?

Comment: Go to terminal and find `param` or navigate to `your_project_directory/log/development.rb`

Comment: Development.rb shows what happens in console. I updated my def create. Also to include I have Private def friendship_params
    params.require(:friendship).permit(:user_id, :friend_id)
  end.

Comment: In console after being run I get Started POST "/friendships?friend_id=john21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-11 09:59:11 -0400
Processing by FriendshipsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"wC8jIOy7DNUMlLQA8B3c0W78mkRFBAgcpV50OeovBlI=", "friend_id"=>"john21"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

Comment: (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "friendships" ("created_at", "friend_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-09-11 13:59:11.377335"], ["friend_id", 0], ["updated_at", "2015-09-11 13:59:11.377335"], ["user_id", 2]]

Comment: ok. it says that `Started POST "/friendships?friend_id=john21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-11 09:59:11 -0400 Processing by FriendshipsController#create`
you can see URL your `friend_id = john21` but it should be some integer. hope you can change it to integer

Comment: thank you. I realized the issue is due to the extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :user_name, use: :slugged (friendly gem). Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the user.id rather than the integer.

Comment: yet to grasp why but it's working perfectly now. I tried using what you've mentioned and shown. Thank you a lot.